# How do I get Wireshark to read header-less pcap files without a UDP/IP/Ethernet header?

Tags: udp, wireshark, pcap, packet-capture

Does Wireshark support a format that doesn't require TCP/UDP/Ethernet headers in every packet?

**Any other (non-pcap) formats wireshark supports would be appreciated.** I need to get header-less data into wireshark for further examination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently this IS possible with newer versions. See their [How To Dissect Anything](http://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDissectAnything) wiki entry.

Basically, in the `pcap header` you set the `network linktype DLT` to `USER DLT #147` decimal. Pcap files are [simple to create](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat).

Then in wireshark `Edit->Preferences->Protocols->DLT_USER->Edit Encapsulations Table`, fill in the GUI dialog. And voila! it parses raw packets.

**UPDATE**: This doesn't support some protocols (like DNS). But you can possibly append fake headers using text2pcap (development version as of Dec-2010).